# The number of solutions to the Diophantine-like inequality

Tags: diophantine-equations, generating-functions

Let $n$ and $m$ be positive integers. Find the number of integral solutions to the inequality $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_m \leq n$ such that $x_i ≥ 2i$ for all $i\in \{1, 2, \ldots, m\}$.

My approach is as follows. By using generating functions, I can find the number of integral solutions for each equation $x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_m = k$, where $k\leq n$. But when adding them up to get a simplified form, that would be so complicated. Is there any other technique to do this problem?

Any approach is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two comments. First, to change the inequality to an equality, you can add a "dummy" variable, like $x_1+\dots+x_m+y=n$. This saves summing solutions to other equations, as you had suggested. Second, to account for any lower bound like $x\ge b$, you can subtract $b$ from both sides of the equality and make a new variable, say $x_1'=x_1-b\ge0$. For the lower bounds you posed, this amounts to subtracting $2+4+\dots+ 2m=m(m+1)$ from $n$. Combining these two ideas results in a concise solution.